# Making a .bat in to find a public folder location. trouble making it ask the user to enter mailbox address

Tags: powershell, batch-file, prompt

As I said in the title, I am trying to make a .bat that will simply prompt the user to enter the email address of the public folder they are looking for.

So far, I use the following command in exchange shell to do it manually:

```
Get-Recipient -Identity  "entreprise@xyz.com" | Get-MailPublicFolder  | Get-PublicFolder
```

Is it possible to have a .bat that will ask the user to enter the email address?

I am completely new to this, I went on google, I found a few thing about ''read-host'', but I don't know how to use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
$emailAddress = Read-Host "Enter address:"
Get-Recipient -Identity $emailAddress | Get-MailPublicFolder | Get-PublicFolder
```

There's also a great resource here: http://waynes-world-it.blogspot.co.nz/2013/04/exchange-powershell-commands.html if that doesnt do it for you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help !

I did a .PS1 using this:

```
    Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin
    $emailAddress = Read-Host "Adresse courriel:" !
    Get-MailPublicFolder $emailAddress |Get-PublicFolder
    pause
```